# ng-repeat not working with table <tr> but works with list <li>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following code: [Code on Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ULoa3SxPAFIPdHTvbguF?p=preview)

I am trying to use `ng-repeat` within a table. But that doesnt work. Whereas the same code works for list `<li>`

Here is a snippet of the same.

```
<h1>Using list</h1>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in sampleArray">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
<h1>Using Table</h1>
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in sampleArray">{{item}}</tr>
</table>
```

Is it incorrect to use ng-repeat within `<tr>`. How could i get the table usage right.

Comment: You might want to put in some `<td>` in the `<tr>`: `<tr ng-repeat=""><td>{{item}}</td></tr>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [W3C HTML Table definition](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

> Tables are defined with the  tag.
>
> Tables are divided into table rows with the  tag.
>
> Table rows are divided into table data with the  tag.
>
> A table row can also be divided into table headings with the  tag.

So the root cause is that you miss a `<td>` or `<th>` element inside your `<tr>` element

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in sampleArray"><td>{{item}}</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

As you building a table with the `ng-repeat`, you should specify the content of each row cells, with the `td` tag like this:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in sampleArray">
    <td>{{$index}}</td>
    <td>{{item}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, checked on the plunker,

You need to remember to put in the `<td>` into the `<tr>`. `<td>` is display element and `<tr>` is structural.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in sampleArray"><td>{{item}}</td></tr>
```