# How can i link external json file in Angular controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm trying to make my first Angular JS project and now i need to export the json array from my controller to an external json file, this is my controller with the json:

```
Fantacalcio.controller('fantacalcioController', function($scope){
  $scope.miaSquadra = [
      {
        Giocatore: {
          nome: "Orestis",
          cognome:"Karnezis"
        },
          mediaVoto: "4.91",
          squadra: "Udinese"
        },

    .....
        Giocatore: {
          nome: "Patrick",
          cognome:"Schick"
        },
          mediaVoto: "6.97",
          ruolo: "attaccante",
          squadra:"Sampdoria"
      }
];
```

});

and this is my component:

```
Fantacalcio.component('tabella', {
    templateUrl: 'components/tabella.html',
    controller: 'fantacalcioController'
  });
```

How could i put the json array in an external json file?
I know i should use $http to make a get request, but i don't know how to use it, i tried this solution https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07 but i can't make it work.

Thank you.

Comment: are you running app using static http server? https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07 solution will work if you running app using server.

Comment: Yes, i'm running the app with a local server (node.js http server).

Comment: can you post code pls. controller and html files

Comment: instead of using ng-repeat="phone in phones" use ng-repeat="p in phones". I also don't know why it is not taking phone in ng-repeat. But i change it and it is working now. <p ng-repeat="p in phones">{{p.id}} {{p.name}} {{p.city}}</p>

Comment: it was only due to - i was repeating rows without having table. we must have included tr inside table to work - check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28525986/ng-repeat-not-working-with-table-tr-but-works-with-list-li

Answer (score 0):

write like:

```
url : '/1',
templateUrl : 'partials/1.html',
controller : function($scope, $http, $log){
  $http.get('phones/phones.json').then(function(response) {
      $scope.phones = response.data.phones;
  });
}
```

use $scope instead of self this in component or write following code in  controller "fantacalcioController"

```
  $http.get('phones/phones.json').then(function(response) {
      $log.log(response.data.phones);
      $scope.phones = response.data.phones;
  });
```

where phones folder is in your app root folder. and phones.json inside phones folder.

Comment: let me know if this helps you.